# How to select dynamic list values based on JS react with Selenium Webdriver and Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I am trying to select first value with selenium web driver and java   from drop down list values build on js , I'm getting some problems to allocate list that is dynamic and not presented in Dom .

I am tried to allocate manually and with recorder but its not work for me .

How should selector looks like to be ?
css,xpath ?

[screen shot of web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQHOS.png)

Comment: Looks like you have to click on list first and then you have to click on the element.I can see the element in that image but if you could put the html of shape list as well that will be great.

Comment: I will share it . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here when you are performing the actions on particular list it is showing NoSuchElementException because it is not present in the DOM. Developer is calling the list with the ReactJs List functions, but here as a QA or Test Engineer you need to select the first item in the list. When you are not getting the list of items by using Select Class, then you have to perform the Keyboard Actions using Actions class.

Example :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQHOS.png

WebElement variable = userWebElement;
Actions action = new Actions();
action.moveToElement(variable).click().sendKeys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

//Here when you missing any keyboard action separate them. And give Thread.sleep in the middle to pause the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly there are two approaches using selenium webdriver.

1. if the "Princess" is a webelement (you can inspect it), you need to find and click the dropdown webelement first and than find and click webelement "Princess"
2. if the "Princess" is not a webelement (unable to inspect), you need to `Select` it:

   ```
   new Select(LOCATOR OF THE DROPDOWN).selectByValue("Princess");
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I will try this one.